# NHibernate 1.2 Id Generated by Database Trigger

Tags: nhibernate

In NHibernate 1.2 is it possible to have the ID generated by a database trigger? Basically we need to change one of our tables to stop using a sequence and instead use a trigger to generate the primary key. So obviously I need to update the nhibernate mapping to use a different generator class but I'm not sure what class I should use, or even if this is supported in 1.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate allows you to do this but only [starting from 2.1.0](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/nh2-1-0-new-generators.aspx):

> **trigger-identity**
>
> The “trigger-identity” is a NHibernate specific feature where the POID
>   is generated by the RDBMS at the INSERT query trough a BEFORE INSERT
>   trigger. In this case you can use any supported type, including custom
>   type, with the limitation of “single-column” (so far)...
>
> **select**
>
> The “select” generator is a deviation of the “trigger-identity”. This
>   generator work together with natural-id feature. The difference
>   “trigger-identity” is that the POID value is retrieved by a SELECT
>   using the natural-id fields as filter...

If you don't want to upgrade to later versions of NHibernate (because of .NET 1.1?) then you can try [Ayende's custom dialect solution](http://ayende.com/blog/2852/how-to-get-nhibernate-to-work-with-pk-values-generated-by-a-trigger) or extend NHibernate as [suggested here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=980364).